# How to open terminal in run level 1?

Tags: init, fsck

I entered my run level 1 using `init 1` for running `fsck -t ext4 /dev/sda1` for fixing my file system problem. I didn't see any terminal where I can run command. I saw only a blank black skin.

I also searched in google but no solution was found.

Now , what can I do?

Comment: Was there a prompt or just an empty blank screen?  If there is a prompt, it is the terminal.

Comment: Just an empty blank skin.